# Asymptotic approximation to radial wave function

Tags: asymptotics, approximation

This seemingly easy analysis is driving me up the wall.

$$\frac{\text{d}^{2}u}{\text{d}\rho^{2}}=\left[1-\frac{\rho_{0}}{\rho}+\frac{l(l+1)}{\rho^{2}}\right]u$$

why is it for

$$\rho\rightarrow0,$$ we get 
$$\frac{\text{d}^{2}u}{\text{d}\rho^{2}}=\frac{l(l+1)}{\rho^{2}}u$$

The whole dam thing obviously goes to infinity!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing the three terms on the right hand side (for $\rho\to0$), you see that
$$1 \ll \frac{\rho_0}{\rho} \ll \frac{l (l+1)}{\rho^2}$$
in the sense that their ratio goes to 0. So for $\rho\to0$, the centrifugal term $l(l+1)/\rho^2$ dominates and we can neglect the other two.